Making an enum available to pass it into a function in C
I am running into a C programming problem that I can't wrap my head around.  I tried passing an enum into a function, but my compiler (Microchip's xc16 via MPLabx) is throwing an error.
I have a global.h header file that defines an enum:
typedef enum
{
   INIT,
   VALID_DATA,
   INVALID_DATA,
   ETC.
}SYS_STATUS

In a separate header file, I have the following function declaration:
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
#endif

void Set_Lamp(SYS_STATUS);

Then in the actual function definition in lamp.c, I have:
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
#endif

#include "lamp.h"

void Set_Lamp(SYS_STATUS sysStat)
{
   // Do stuff...
}

However, when I compile, I get a warning:

warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration

and an error:

error: expected ')' before 'sysStat'

Can you not pass an enum into a function, or am I just doing something stupid?

Your header does not know what SYS_STATUS is. Include your global.h in it. Not sure why you have the GLOBAL_H guard in there as you say it is a separate header...

Aside, why do you have #ifndef GLOBAL_H etc in other files which aren't global.h? You should place that in the header file so that the compiler only parses it once in any compilation, no matter how many times it is included by other files.

Also, why do you define GLOBAL_H in lamp.c ? - that seems wrong.

As wll as #include "lamp.h" you need #include "global.h". The #ifndef GLOBAL_H and #define GLOBAL_H are only needed inside the "global.h" file

While failing to include the declaration for SYS_STATUS in your “a separate header file” is likely the problem, the code you have shown yields compiler errors due to the incorrect . in ETC. and the missing ; after SYS_STATUS in the typedef. When posting a Stack Overflow question like this, prepare a [mre] that shows exactly code that demonstrates the problem. You should provide code that enables other people to reproduce the problem and to eliminate problems caused by the unrelated errors in the code you posted.

you need  to:
enums.h:
#ifndef EMUMS_H
#define EMUMS_H

typedef enum
{
   INIT,
   VALID_DATA,
   INVALID_DATA,
   ETC.
}SYS_STATUS

#endif

global.h:
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include "enums.h"

void Set_Lamp(SYS_STATUS);

#endif

in your source file:
#include "global.h"

void Set_Lamp(SYS_STATUS sysStat)
{

   //Do stuff...

}

Of course, you can place the enum directly in the global.h file.
Side note: In your .h file the guard does not guard anything.

Thank you for the response (sorry so late, it's been a week...)! That was the trick. Also, the guards were a bad copy paste job on my part. Thank you again for your help!
